# gvm `The program 'go' is currently not installed`

Tags: go, gvm

I just installed `gvm` with `go1.3`, but when I try to `go version` I have `The program 'go' is currently not installed` message. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gvm go1.3 --default` fixed this

Answer (score 0):

Check your `$PATH` environment variable once you have [used gvm](http://gvmtool.net/) (`gvm install` or `gvm use`).
It should include the `bin/` folder of your `go` installation folder.
For instance: `/usr/lib/go/bin`

[Issue 187](https://github.com/gvmtool/gvm/issues/187) reports:

> Currently `GVM` assumes it is in sole charge of the `*_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables and puts it's paths first.
>   Since the default is to execute the `GVM` initialization last this overwrites any settings the user may have set up, in my case `GROOVY_HOME` and `PATH` are set as I need them then GVM overwrites the settings.
>
> Thus currently `GVM` does not "play nice" with a sophisticated users' set up.

Comment: this is for `grails`, but I need `go`

Comment: @cnaize I understand. First, make sure go is in your $PATH, and the command is working. Then try gvm, and see if it still work.